# Making scene making from real clicked images for Google cardboard

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I know about Google cardboard and I want to make say a campus tour of any company which will be handled by head movements in Google Cardboard with unity how to make campus buildings from the real images which I clicked by my camera.I am new to unity and much aware with android coding.could you link any unity tutorial.
And second thing my approach toward this idea is good with unity or it should be with android.

**i want to make thing like this** [youtube link which i want](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MsVkT_nbMQ) **Please suggest**

Comment: By real images you mean normal photos or a photosphere?

Comment: normal photos like the images clicked by mobile phone....i want to make the building so i clicked a nice image of that building.....and i want to use that image for android cardboard..so that user can move his/her head to roam around that building

Comment: As far as i know, my answer provided you a way to make this. Please refine your question as for what is missing.

Comment: @ChanibaL want to make like this in cardboard https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVFmo9HBvvA

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could position a great lot of images in 3D space and have a scene with a very modern-art-like look - but it's much easier to do a spherical image and drag it to a sphere.

You can use a digital camera and [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) to stitch photos manually for better quality or just take any android phone with a gyroscope and semi-good camera and do a [photosphere](http://www.google.com/maps/about/contribute/photosphere/).

After getting a spherical image, just drag it to a sphere with [reversed normals](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ReverseNormals) and put the VR camera in it's center - voilla, you've got a VR app.

A good idea would be to allow the user some interaction, moving between scenes etc. Usually there is a point where you look and either wait a bit or press the cardboard button.

Comment: ( 1.) i made cube and then imported the real image over cube but image is overlapped in roof and floor what shoud i do and ( 2.) The main thing is the image is all inverted the thing in real life which exists in right is appearing in left in the virtual mobile view........( 3 ) i also want to move or you can say roam around inside the cube in that  virtual room

Comment: 1: overlapping - you have to fix this in external programs like photoshop or gimp; if you don't want them to look bad you should do your images as proper spherical equirectangular textures or cubemaps - with hugin.

Comment: 2: inverting an image in an axis (mirroring) - play with the cube's scale. For example this might require an `-1` scale in `x` and `z` coordinates.

Comment: 3: looking around will work, but moving inside that cube will never look good - it's just a picture from one point, you do not have depth information in the pictures, so any movement will distort perspective. What you can do is switch between pictures, if you make them close enough that will work.

Comment: ok got your point.....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MsVkT_nbMQ in this youtube video at time 0:50 sec how should i implement that thing .Please do refer any link or tutorial.